# Set expiry date for application

Tags: c#, drm

I want to set expire date for my C# Windows application.

It means that i.e after 30 days my app won't work. It is easy to do when we use system time, it means whenever my program starts i check today date and expire date.

The problem is if the user changes system time, my comparison won't be correct.

What other ways can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be keep a dummy .dll file in your app install folder, open it and keep the number of days and install date time. Every time application loads up, check it. .Dll files folks wont try to open and read. May be you can encrypt and store in it too. This could be very simple.

Comment: Are you saying that this would be a plaintext file simply named as `.dll`?

Comment: Yea it can be, hence said its the simplest solution. Mostly to fool the user that its a application file, but it just has some encrypted installed datetime and number of max days.

Comment: first i thinked at this solution,but we want to set expire date for number of days not number of application loading and how many times application loads ?! so now how can i determine Now Date to compare with expire date that is in dll ?!

Comment: As said, when you install the application, make the installsheild (if thats how u publish it) to launch the app (mandatory), as soon as the app loads, create this file and take the system time. By now, you have when its installed and you already know how many days it can run. Just encrypt the DT in that file and save it. So every load, read this value and calculate the remaining days. The rest of logic you know right?

Comment: Though this is a method I'd never implement in my project, but still a good one.. +1

Answer (score 4):

I would figure out a better way to get people to want to pay for the application, because fighting it can be a very futile effort, although you can make it more difficult with things like hardware dongles, phone home services, etc.  If your price point is not high, customers won't want to put up with this.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of defense is to check with a server, checking out their system time so that the user cannot change his own. Also try to hide the start date (under some dummy name in the registry perhaps). These are pretty futile things though, smart users will be able to 'crack' this with minimal effort.

Comment: Checking with a server somewhere online is forcing the client to have an internet connection. Unless your application doesn't need any connection to a remote server then this isn't really an option I quess.

Comment: it will be a bit limitation to my app because of my app don't need internet connection .

Comment: Internet connection can never be acceptable.. Every app cannot have internet access..

Answer (score 1):

It's trivial to disassemble a C# application, so whatever you implement will be liable to easy circumvention.  The best choice, in my opinion is to use third-party Licensing tools but do bear in mind that all can be circumvented, although they will be more robust.

Comment: you mean i use a license such as some softwares pruduce like .NET Reactor !?

Comment: That's right. .NET Reactor, Licensespot, etc.  There are many trialware/timebomb licensing solutions out there, but you always have to remember that none of them are perfect.  A mature, third-party licensing solution is going to be more robust than something you coded overnight though, particularly in an application that is trivial to disassemble.

Comment: i used .NET Reactor but didn't affect !

Comment: Apologies.  You need [intellilock](http://www.eziriz.com/intellilock.htm) which is made by the same organisation.

Comment: i also used that but nothing done !!! i set expire date to today => and then clicked on finilize => but nothing done !

Answer (score 1):

How likely is your app to be pirated and is it worth the time/expense to do anything more than cursory checks?

It might be easier to simply have two versions of a DLL - one that must communicate with a server every X days to make sure it's still active and the "unlocked" (purchased) version.

As has been noted, determined users will find a way around whatever you do so you have to evaluate effort/return to determine how much attempting to secure your app is worth.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a website that keeps the time to determine how long the program was installed.

You are probably going to get advice saying that it is not woth your effort.